# Create subplot in Matplotlib by Column value

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot for each value in "CurveName" column. The x-axis should be "Tenor" and y-axis should be "Difference".

[image]

I tried the following:

```
for crv in set(df['CurveName']):
    x = df.loc[df['CurveName']==crv, p_df['Tenor']]
    y = df.loc[df['CurveName']==crv, p_df['Difference']]

    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.show()
```

I get a KeyError:
[image]

It would be ideal that I can create a subplot for each value within "CurveName", but I struggled to do it.

If any further details are needed, please don't hesitate in letting me know

Comment: According to the error, your dataframe is wrong. The error indicates all the dates are in a single string.

Comment: What does it mean they are in a single string? That they weren't convered to Datetime?

Comment: `df.groupby('CurveName').plot('Tenor', 'Difference')`